# RegEx to extract/group the all values which comes after colon from below string in Java

Tags: java, regex

I've got a string like this:

```
1454974419:1234;1454974448:3255,2255,66789
```

I would like to extract/group these values by using regular expression in java.

```
1234
```

```
3255
```

```
2255
```

```
66789
```

Comment: Please show what you have come up so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this lookbehind and negation based regex:

```
(?<=[:,])[^;,]+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uB5jT5/1)

**Breakup:**

```
(?<=[:,])  # lookbehind to assert if previous char is : or ,
[^;,]+     # match 1 or more of anything that is not a ; or ,
```

Comment: great, worked like charm. Thanks. Had to surround with () then able to extract by Pattern.compile("((?<=[:,])[^;,]+)");

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
String yourString= "1454974419:1234;1454974448:3255,2255,66789";
          Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
          Matcher myMatcher = myPattern.matcher(yourString);
            while(myMatcher.find())
            {
                String temp= myMatcher.group();
                yourString=yourString.replaceAll("\\"+temp, "");
            }
System.out.println(yourString);
```

Comment: Sorry,  it's not what I wanted. Please try by using the regex in accepted answer.

Comment: I gave this answer because Pattern and Matcher are from the Regex libraries.